# Difference between ModuleSpawn and ModuleInvoke in Marklogic?

Tags: marklogic

I have gone through entire website of Marklogic but i am not finding what are ModuleSpawn  and ModuleInvoke class and why are we using them and difference between them.

Do anyone have idea about that?

Comment: I have found one difference that ModuleInvoke class is used when .xqy query resident in the server while ModuleSpawn is used when .zqy query resident server-side.

Comment: ModuleSpawn is asynchronous method while ModuleInvoke is synchronous.

Answer (score 3):

Both are subclasses of http://docs.marklogic.com/7.0/javadoc/xcc/com/marklogic/xcc/Request.html

The key difference is that ModuleSpawn is ["spawned asynchronously by the MarkLogic Server"](http://docs.marklogic.com/7.0/javadoc/xcc/com/marklogic/xcc/ModuleSpawn.html). That is, it runs on the task server instead of the xdbc server.